# I'm getting this error: ',' expected.ts(1005) . I have tried using the latest compiler versions but it wont go away. Please advise

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, solidity-0.8.x, hardhat-deploy

[image: The error is on line 9]
The error is on line 9. I can't really tell what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one  I can help!, just add one comma after the URL

```
url:'asdasdad',
account:[xxx]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It did. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to have helped. Could you mark the question as solved, it would help others!